# extract percentage explained variance in ssa result (Rssa)

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition

I'm working with the Rssa package to decompose time series, witch works fine except that I can't get the percentage of explained variance from each eigenvector (if these are the right words to explain this). However, these percentages are noted on top on one of the graphs I can plot with this package.
Let me give an example:

```
d=rnorm(200,10,3)
plot(d,type="l")
ssa=ssa(d, L = 100,digits=0)
plot(ssa,type="vector")   #the percentage I want is in the title of each individual graph

# to reconstruct the trend and the residuals
res <- reconstruct(ssa, groups = list(1))
trend <- res$F1
```

How do I get these percentages in a vector? Especially since I want to loop over multiple series.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the code for weighted norm of the series by component is hidden in the package.
I extract the code from `Rssa:::.plot.ssa.vectors.1d.ssa` and wrapped it a small function:

```
component_wnorm <- 
function(x) {
  idx <- seq_len(min(nsigma(x), 10))
  x <- ssa
  total <- wnorm(x)^2
  round(100*x$sigma[idx]^2 / total, digits = 2)
}

component_wnorm(ssa)
[1] 92.02  0.35  0.34  0.27  0.27  0.25  0.22  0.20  0.20  0.18
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The recent version of Rssa has the function `contributions`.
Therefore, you can use

```
> s <- ssa(d, L=100)
> c <- contributions(s)*100
> print(c[1:10], digits = 2)
 [1] 92.41  0.28  0.26  0.26  0.26  0.23  0.23  0.21  0.20  0.20
```